# R TensorFlow tfestimators - SVM and random forest how to?

Tags: r, tensorflow, svm, random-forest

The R package tfestimators (https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tfestimators/) lists several canned estimators currently available:

linear_regressor() Linear regressor model.

linear_classifier() Linear classifier model.

dnn_regressor() DNN Regression.

dnn_classifier() DNN Classification.

dnn_linear_combined_regressor() DNN Linear Combined Regression.

dnn_linear_combined_classifier() DNN Linear Combined Classification.

There is mention of SVMs and random forests "coming soon". Does anyone know of a way to implement SVMs and random forests in tensorflow through R at this time?

Thanks very much!